# publishing negative values from command line

Tags: ros-fuerte, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Is it possible to publish negative values via rostopic pub ?
I tried

```
rostopic pub -1 /my_point geometry_msgs/Point 1 2 3
```

with no problem, but when I try

```
rostopic pub -1 /my_point geometry_msgs/Point 1 -2 3
```

it says an error:

```
Usage: rostopic pub /topic type [args...]

rostopic: error: no such option: -2
```

Is it anyhow possible to publish negative values from terminal?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61598/publishing-negative-values-from-command-line/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See also the comment [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine#Command-line_and_negative_numbers) on using negative numbers with ROS command-line tools.  As described in the link, you can use the `--` flag to tell the parser to stop looking for additional command-line options.

So, the following should also work:

```
rostopic pub -1 /my_point geometry_msgs/Point -- 1 -2 3
```

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try

```
rostopic pub -1 /my_point geometry_msgs/Point '{x: 1, y: -2, z: 3}'
```

Here is the page [YAML on the ROS command line](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/YAMLCommandLine)

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-04-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3